# Graphical man pages viewer in Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, command-line

There is a feature in terminal to view man-page of selected string in external window with **⌃⌘?** shortcut.

But it has a priority to display preinstalled man pages. So for example I've installed gnu coreutils with homebrew and have edited man-pages search path. And if I do `man ls` in console I get man-page from gnu coreutils but help menu action gives me bsd man-page.

Is it possible to fix man-pages search path for it?

Comment: Try running `which man`. Mine is `/usr/bin/man` but yours may have changed by the installation of the GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that you can use [Dash](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12#). It is an application for having and reading different programming languages docsets offline. It also has the ability to read the man pages available on your system.