# Unwanted man page widget

Tags: terminal, keyboard, widgets

Since my last update, to macOS_14.3.1_23D60 on 8 Feb 2024, I frequently have an unwanted [man page widget appearing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127124/graphical-man-pages-viewer-in-terminal-app) in front of the Terminal.  The odd thing is, it is almost always empty, and usually happens after typing a space—**never** after using any combination keys and never with any text selected.

**How can I stop it?**